# How to search people born on a specific day and month, doesn't matter the year?

Tags: freebase

I want to create a query that returns people born on, for example, May 2nd - doesn't matter the year.
How to do this search in MQL?
Thanks
Carlos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to do this query in MQL. You can do this with the Freebase Search API like this though:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?filter=(all+/people/person/date_of_birth:"-05-02")&output=(/people/person/date_of_birth)
```